# Realm @count query issue

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I have tried to use the `@count` function to get data according to that but it somehow crashed without crash report.

Here is the **code**

```
class PSMedia: Object {
    @objc dynamic var id = ""

    @objc dynamic var promotional_status = false

    var promotions = List<String>()
}
```

And here is that query that caused an issue

`realm.objects(PSMedia.self).filter("promotions.@count <= 5")`

What's wrong here? I have followed realm swift doc and used the `@count` function same as described in that doc.

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure @count does not work on Lists of primitives. Realm didn't used to support lists of primitives at all, it now does but there is some missing functionality.

**EDIT:** Release 10.7 added support for filters/queries as well as aggregate functions on primitives so the below info is no longer completely valid. However, it's still something to be aware of.

Change your promotions to be a list of other realm objects

```
class PromotionClass: Object {
   @objc dynamic var promotion = ""
}
```

and then

```
class PSMedia: Object {
    @objc dynamic var id = ""
    @objc dynamic var promotional_status = false
    let promotions = List<PromotionClass>()
}
```

then this will work

```
realm.objects(PSMedia.self).filter("promotions.@count <= 5")
```

**EDIT**

Yep, that's correct. It's not supported. Here's the Github link for that issue

[Swift docs should make it clear that filtering by `someListOfPrimitives.@count` isn't supported #6079](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/6079)

Comment: In [realm doc.](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#filtering), it suggestes that `The aggregate expressions @count, @min, @max, @sum and @avg are supported on List and Results properties, e.g. realm.objects(Company.self).filter("employees.@count > 5") to find all companies with more than five employees.` So, I think it should support `@count` function with my structure as well but it doesn't.

Comment: But how it's stored directly to promotions? I have array of string, so how does it automatically stored in `PSMedia`?

Comment: @EICaptainv2.0 Hmm. An *array of string*? Realm doesn't have a Array objects; there are Lists and Results which are similar in functionality. Maybe that's what you mean? *how does it automatically stored in PSMedia*. Not sure I understand the question. To filter or count on a List object, the elements stored in the list cannot be primitive like a String. They need to be Realm objects as shown in my answer. You can then filter for specific strings or use count. If you want to add Promotion objects, create it, populate the property and the add it t the promotions List in PSMedia.

Comment: @EICaptainv2.0 let me know if you need that code and I will update my answer.